# In a symmetric distribution, Median=Mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Does the mean=median in a symmetric distribution?

Comment: in a symmetric distribution mean=median=mode.

Comment: The mean might not exist (for example, [the standard Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)).

Comment: if median exists mean will exist too. since median is the mid value of an arrayed data set and if median exists then mean will eixst too. the same can not be said of mode. so in other words in a symmetric distribution median=mean

Comment: in case of cauchy distribution mean does not exist. you are right

Comment: @SA-255525 The symmetric distribution might not be unimodal... so mode$\neq$median or mean. Either way, how does one prove that
in a symmetric distribution mean=median (when both exist)? Any bibliography/reference?

Answer (score 1):

if $X$ and $c-X$ have the same distribution, then means of $X$ and $c-X$ are the same (if they exist), hence are equal to $\frac c2$. By the same reasoning, the medians are the same (if they exist) and hence are also $\frac c2$.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you can assume that X and c-X have the same distribution...

Comment: Medians exist (at least for random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$) but they are not always unique: your $\frac{c}{2}$ comment requires uniqueness.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea: How else would you define a  symmetric distribution?

Comment: @Henry, by by the density function, or mass funtion, and then we would have to prove the assertion in Hagen's answer.

Comment: @Henry but it's really the same. I get it now. ;)